# Help Jarl Olaf in his raids

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Jarl Olaf lives in a beautiful village, Stackholm. In every year he is thinking about raiding a place to get some golden jewelery, food and <s>programmers</s> <s>woman</s> slaves.

He is a good person but not the brightest one, so you need to help him decide the next target. He has three targets in his mind: Jarl Burg, England and Paris.

Jarl Burg is the closest, he lives In Norway, Olaf can sail there all year.

England is a longer journey, it will took him 2 months, but he wants to settle down a bit, so he must start his journey three month before winter and he also won't start it in winter.

Paris is far-far away, to sail there will took 3 months, need more man, more time to settle down, so 5 months before winter they need to be on the sea, but won't start in winter.

**Challenge**

Your task is to get the starting month as an input (string or number you decide) and decide where to sail. If more possible targets crossing each other then decide randomly where to go.

Your output will be the army of the ships. (3-6-9 ships)

**Help**

Olaf need only 3 ships to Jarl Burg, 6 to England and 9 to Paris.

1 ship is 2 tab long, the arragement of the ships are provided in the test cases for all three possibilities.

The second ships starts where the first ends, the third one start in the middle of the first and there is a new line between the second and the third ships.

The direction of the oars are significant.

Winter month are January (1), February (2), December (12).

**Test cases**

**Input:**

6

**Output:**

```
  / / /                           / / /
<■■■■■■»                        <■■■■■■»
  \ \ \                           \ \ \
          / / /                           / / /
        <■■■■■■»                        <■■■■■■»
          \ \ \                           \ \ \
                  / / /
     \ \ \      <■■■■■■»             \ \ \
    <■■■■■■»      \ \ \             <■■■■■■»
     / / /                / / /      / / /
                        <■■■■■■»
                          \ \ \

                     \ \ \
                    <■■■■■■»
                     / / /
```

**Input:**

December

**Output:**

```
  / / / 
<■■■■■■»
  \ \ \ 
          / / / 
        <■■■■■■»
          \ \ \ 

     \ \ \  
    <■■■■■■»
     / / /
```

**Input:**

8

**Output:**

```
  / / / 
<■■■■■■»
  \ \ \ 
          / / / 
        <■■■■■■»
          \ \ \ 
                  / / /
     \ \ \      <■■■■■■»
    <■■■■■■»      \ \ \ 
     / / /                / / / 
                        <■■■■■■»
                          \ \ \

                     \ \ \
                    <■■■■■■»
                     / / /
```

This is code-golf challenge, so the answer with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: How do we determine how many ships to output? Is the direction of the oars significant? What months are considered winter? Is the placement of the ships significant?

Comment: I just edit my question to answer you.

Comment: Do we need to handle the input month as a number and as text, or can we choose one?

Comment: The input type is in the question, but it can be both number and text.

Comment: Can you just provide us with each month's output numbers, or possible output numbers?